# WildFly returns just "not found" no 404

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, wildfly

I'm running WildFly 9 and for some reason all pages return a "not found" with "Error" for the title.

I can't find what I'm missing.

My `web.xml` has the following:

```
<display-name>enterprise-web</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I'm pointing the the following url:

```
http://localhost:8080/enterprise-web/index.xhtml
```

Webcontent directory: 
[image: WebContent]

Comment: Have a look in the server log if everything started up correctly. Perhaps post your server log and server configuration.

Comment: Where did you learn that you should be using that URL pattern for a servlet and particularly a MVC controller servlet? I've never seen this being recommended in any sane book/tutorial. This suggests that you're using the wrong learning resources to learn JSF. I recommend you to start at our JSF wiki page: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info This is also linked in bottom of the duplicate answer which you've already been referred to in [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34281453/faces-pages-do-not-render-wildfly).